# having trouble setting up smbsrc.net in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, symbol-server

- I have setup `https://nuget.smbsrc.net/` as a symbol file location in VS2015 and also followed the insructions on symbolsource.org
- In the "Modules" window, while debugging, I right-click on a DLL that was installed via a NuGet package for which I know a symbol package has been published for. I can verify this using

`nuget list OBeautifulCode.AutoFakeItEasy -prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net/`

- I click on 'Symbol Load Information'
- I see the following at the bottom of the text box

`SYMSRV:  https://nuget.smbsrc.net/: not available`

`https://nuget.smbsrc.net/: Symbols not found on symbol server.`

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an issue with pre-release nuget packages?

Comment: Opened a command prompt, updated NuGet using "NuGet update -self" and executed "nuget list OBeautifulCode.AutoFakeItEasy -prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net/". The response is: BeautifulCode.AutoFakeItEasy 1.0.81-fix-at-12MXML. Maybe a network problem?

Comment: @JeroenHeier - correct.  I see the same response that you do - proving that the symbol package is there.  Not sure about network problem, I have no problem installing nuget packages and I've got a great connection.

Comment: Do you still have this problem or have you manage to solve it? I am strugling with the exact same issue at the moment

Comment: I stopped trying =(

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing. For me it was the way I entered the symbol server path in visual studio.  Seems like a trailing slash breaks things.

right:

https://nuget.smbsrc.net

wrong:

https://nuget.smbsrc.net/

Comment: Thanks for posting!  I'll give it a shot the next time I need symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue when I push a Symbol NuGet package (not a pre-release version) to symbolsource.org based on following tutorial and configure the Visual Studio with [this tutorial](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages

So I add comments for this issue under this tutorial to confirm whether there has any problem on the symbolsource.org and the steps in introduced.